# curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: Operation timed out, errno 60

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew

I am opening a new question because I have tried answers to similar questions but they didn't work. Even after setting the https.postBuffer to 500MB, the problem still persists.

I just got a new Macbook with an M1 Pro chip, and since then I have been trying to install Homebrew, but every time it shows a curl error. I also changed the wifi network check with VPN and without VPN, but it is not working. you can see below. Is there any solution for this?

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: Operation timed out, errno 60
```

Comment: I think it is the network problem. @Younas